# Any way to tell .profile.bashrc that script is already running?

Tags: bash

I was wondering if there is any argument that I can add to my bash script so it won't be executed again on log on, because it' already executed on reboot. That causes the script to stop, when runned second time.

Bash:

```
if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi

mesg n || true

cd /root/Boti/Gianni/
bash /root/Boti/Gianni/comanda.sh
```

I am using Debian 9 on a VPS.

Comment: Does your `/tmp` directory get cleared on reboot? What do you want to do if the script has exited and you run it again?

Comment: It is running in the background with `nohup`. I just want bash to recognize that it's already running and not execute it everytime I log on.

Comment: So you don't care if it dies unexpectedly for some reason? You'll just wait until the next reboot to restart it? (Not rhetorical. It changes the answer.) And does your `/tmp` directory get cleaned on reboot?

Comment: The VPS has an 99,98% uptime. I'm not worried for that. And yes, my `/tmp` it's empty after every reboot.

Comment: I was asking about `comanda.sh` dying, not the VPS being unreliable. `mkdir /tmp/comanda.lock || exit` at start of `comanda.sh` guarantes only one invocation per boot or until the directory is deleted by some other means. Can probably use `/run/lock/comanda.lock` instead.